# Tests for view names failing since upgrading to Django 4.0

Tags: django

In a Django project I have tests that check that a URL uses a specific class-based view. e.g. I have this view:

```py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "home.html"
```

And this test:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import resolve
from myapp import views

class UrlsTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_home_view(self):
        self.assertEqual(resolve("/").func.__name__, views.HomeView.__name__)
```

This test passes in Django 3.x but once I try it with Django 4.0 the test fails with:

```
self.assertEqual(resolve("/").func.__name__, views.HomeView.__name__)
AssertionError: 'view' != 'HomeView'
- view
+ HomeView
```

Obviously something has changed in Django 4.0 but I can't see anything related in [the release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/4.0/).

So, what's changed and how can I make this test work again (or how can I test this in a  better way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `.as_view()`, it thus does *not* return a class object, but a function that will handle requests by creating a new `HomeView` and trigger the corresponding method based on the HTTP method.

You can check if it is a method of the `HomeView` by checking the `.view_class` attribute. Furthermore it is probably better to check if the two classes are the same, not the *names* of these classes:

```
#                                            ↓ no .__name__  ↓
self.assertEqual(resolve('/').func.view_class, views.HomeView)
```

I did some research why comparing the `__name__`s no longer works. Apparently in [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0) they used the [**`update_wrapper(…)`** function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) which sets the `__name__`, `__qualname__`, etc. of one object (in this case the class) to the function. Indeed, in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L76), we can see:

> ```
> @classonlymethod
> def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
>     # …
>     def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
>         # …
>     # …
>
>     # take name and docstring from class
>     update_wrapper(view, cls, updated=())
>     # …
> ```

this has been changed in [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0) where they also explained in [a comment why they do no longer do that [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L73-L75):

> ```
> @classonlymethod
> def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
>     # …
>     # __name__ and __qualname__ are intentionally left unchanged as
>     # view_class should be used to robustly determine the name of the view
>     # instead.
>     # …
> ```

Comment: That does it, thank you! Any idea why this is different in Django 4.0?

Comment: @PhilGyford: No, I'm actually surprised that that worked in 3.x. Did you by any chance turned the view into a class-based one?

Comment: No, I haven't changed the code. I've tested things this way in several Django projects in the past, and it's only now I'm updating things to 4.0 that I've encountered this problem.

Comment: @PhilGyford: I think I found it: in Django-3.0, they used `update_wrapper` https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L76 this copies the name of, in this case, the class to the name of the function. In Django-4.0 the comment says explicitly that they no longer set the `__name__` and `__qual_name__`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/views/generic/base.py#L73

Comment: @PhilGyford: I've updated the answer with the code fragments. Perhaps it is not part of the release notes because it is seen as an "implementation detail". But regardless, as the comment says, using `.view_class` is a more robust way to check if the correct view class is triggered.

Comment: This seems to be a PR that introduced this change:
https://github.com/django/django/pull/14124